# MFC: How do you have CRichEditView print the selection?

Tags: winapi, mfc, cricheditctrl

I can enable the print dialog to show the option to print the selection by `pInfo->m_pPD->m_pd.Flags &= ~PD_NOSELECTION;` in `OnPreparePrinting()` just before the `DoPreparePrinting()` function but if you select the option the object is still printing everything.

If you choose just to print certain pages that works.

So how do you have the `CRichEditView` support the print selection option?

TIA!!

Comment: I think MFC ignores that flag, because printing is handled by `CView` which doesn't know RTF selection. Add `void CMyRichView::OnBeginPrinting(CDC *pdc, CPrintInfo* pinfo){call default ... if(pinfo->m_pPD->m_nFlags || PD_SELECTION){...}}` This tells you if user wants to print the selection. At this point you can save the document, delete the stuff before/after selection, continue with printing, and then restore the document.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commdlg/ns-commdlg-printdlga:

> `PD_NOSELECTION`
>
> Disables the Selection radio button.

Try:

> `PD_SELECTION`
>
> If this flag is set, the Selection radio button is selected.

Comment: I'm able to enable the option, it's just the CRichEditView doesn't honor it.